# Reduce mercurial .hg folder size

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-convert

I have a mercurial repo with several GB under .hg/store/data.
I identified several huge folders under .hg/store/data which start with underscore (e.g.: .hg/store/data/_some_path_example), and they are not present in the working directory.

I tried to use hg convert extension with a filemap with exclude statements, but the directories are still there in the converted repo.
What should be the paths in the exclude statements that would remove the .hg/store/data/_some_path_example paths with underscores?...

Thanks!

Comment: I think I found the meaning of leading underscore in the .hg/store/data/_some_path_example path - it's mercurial's way to say that _s should be uppercase - i.e. in this case - SomePathExample. I'm converting now to see if specifying the path with upper case in filemap would help...

Comment: It sounds like you have a large amount of deleted files in the history that you want to clean up.  `hg manifest --all` may help.  It lists all files from all revisions including deleted and renamed files.  You can then use the `convert` extension to strip those files from history if that is your intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of other's who have the same question/issue:
As I wrote in a comment, the meaning of leading underscore is mercurial's way to specify that the letter coming after the underscore is upper-case.
I inserted exclude lines with correct case letters, and conversion worked as planned.